# Sonar seems to ignore variables set in catch block

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint, false-positive

Does anyone know why SonarQube detects a violation of the rule "Conditionally executed blocks should be reachable" ([squid:S2583](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2583)) in the following example? Is this a false positive?

In this piece of Java code, a file is read and an `EOFException` (or multiple of them) can occur in the process of reading the input stream. Thus, the exception is caught and handled, and a flag is set to remember that it happened. However, Sonar does not consider the line `exHappened = true;` in the first catch block and claims that variable is always `false`:

```
public static boolean doSomething() {
    boolean exHappened = false;
    try (DataInputStream s = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("test"))) {
        LOGGER.info("Doing something...");
    }
    catch (EOFException eof) {   // this Exception can definitely happen
        exHappened = true;
    }
    catch (IOException io) {
        LOGGER.error("sorry", io);
    }

    if (exHappened) {            // Sonar thinks this condition is always false
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

To make it even more clear, add a `throw new EOFException()` into the `try { }`, then the condition will **always** be true and Sonar still claims that it always false...

(I'm using SonarQube 5.6.6 and SonarJava plugin 4.13.0.11627)

Comment: According to https://www.sonarqube.org/community/feedback/, SonarQube Google Group is a better to place to report bugs, and their JIRA is probably the best.

Comment: You are right. Next time I will post questions about possible false-positives in the SonarQube Google Group (their JIRA is read-only, by the way).

Comment: You can post questions to Google Group or here, both channels are monitored by community. What is the version of SonarJava plugin and SonarQube you are using?

Comment: Question is updated: SonarQube 5.6.6 and SonarJava plugin 4.13.0.11627

Comment: Hi @TiborBlenessy, any updates on this?

Comment: see my answer, this is a bug in our data flow engine. Thank you for reporting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem in how catch blocks are handled during data flow analysis in SonarJava. Catch block catching subtype of the exception declared in the throws declaration of called method is not being considered, hence the assignment to the variable is never seen by the engine.

I created following ticket to fix this problem https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2483